# Sending email using python script from an Azure server

Tags: python, azure, smtp, azure-web-app-service

Using a python script, I am trying to send an email.
The mail part of the script looks like -

```
import smtplib
sender = 'abc.xyz@company.com'
receiver = 'abc.xyz@company.com'
message = """From: From Person <abc.xyz@company.com>
To: To Person <abc.xyz@company.com>
Subject: Inbound Folder Check - Alert
Unchanged even after an hour, please check
"""
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('def@company.onmicrosoft.com','Password')
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
```

The error that I am getting is -

> raise SMTPDataError(code, resp) smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'5.2.0
>   STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedE
>   xception.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a
>   permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. ...,
>   20.52176:140FCC8414001010640 10000, 20.50032:140FCC848417101069010000, 0.35180:0A006586, 255.23226:6E010000,
>   255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:0A00EB87, 16.55847:69000000, 1
>   7.43559:0000000090010000000000000D00000000000000, 20.52176:140FCC84140010100A00F 736, 20.50032:140FCC84841710100A00F836, 0.35180:8C010000, 255.23226:40000730, 25
>   5.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:9A010000, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27 962:FA000000, 255.1494:0A00070E, 0.37692:01000100, 0.44092:01000100, 0.41232:010 00100, 0.60208:01000100, 0.37136:01000100, 0.34608:01000100, 0.55056:01000100, 0 .42768:01000100, 0.56112:05000780, 0.52807:00000000, 4.33016:DC040000, 7.40748:0 10000000000010C00000000, 7.57132:000000000000000005000780, 1.63016:32000000, 4.3 9640:DC040000, 8.45434:EC5537826FAD8844ABBA433565F1D57205000780, 5.10786:0000000 031352E32302E313232382E3032303A564931505230314D42323939303A38616433323065392D646
>   338612D343530642D386265322D62646464616261333932613900602005000780,
>   255.1750:4B01 0000, 255.31418:0A004C82, 0.22753:50010000, 255.21817:DC040000, 4.60547:DC040000 , 0.21966:B4100000, 4.30158:DC040000 [Hostname=abc]')

Only help I got on the internet was from the page - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3132755/554-5-2-0-storedrv-deliver-exception-objectnotfoundexception-mapiexcep
And it seems to say clutter is enabled but the folder is not present in the mailbox and suggests to turn off the clutter option which didn’t help.

PS - This works from my local machine within my company network but it is something to do with running it from Azure server.

Comment: have you changed the smtp port number and checked it also?

Comment: @ShehanDhaleesha Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried putting in some random port and I got the following -
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
 party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connectio
n failed because connected host has failed to respond

Seems like the port that I am using is correct but it is something else. The mail server in itself is denying the connection.

Comment: Unrelated to the configuration error (which makes this off-topic for Stack Overflow) you need an empty line between the `Subject:` header and the body.

Comment: @tripleee I think I already have this empty line. It just didn't translate in copy paste :)
What configuration are you talking about? How do I fix this :S

Comment: As the error message (vaguely) tells you, you are not authorized to use this SMTP server to send email claiming to be from this address.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please follow the offical document [How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3#use-your-own-email-server-to-send-email-from-multifunction-devices-and-applications) to make sure whether set up correctly.

Secondly, if you were using Azure VM to send mail via SMTP, you can refer to this document [Understand outbound SMTP problems in Azure VMs](https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-azure/understand-outbound-smtp-problems-azure-vms) to try to fix your issue.

Meanwhile, for coding, there are some resources that may helps.

1. [Python: Send Email via Office 365](https://aventistech.com/2016/03/07/python-send-email-via-office-365-tls/)
2. [Send email on App Service using Office 365 (O365)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2017/03/27/send-mail-on-app-service-using-php-mailer-and-o365/) in PHP
3. [Sending email from an Azure App Service using an O365 SMTP server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/11/sending-email-from-an-azure-web-app-using-an-o365-smtp-server/) in C#

Or using some packages directly like python-o365: [GitHub](https://github.com/O365/python-o365) and [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/O365/).

Finally, there is a service named SendGrid which be used for email service. You can use it to send mail in your scenario on Azure, please refer to the offical tutorial to know [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email) (C#). For Python, you can code via [its REST API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html) or [sendgrid python library](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v2-python-code-example/).